# Can I calculate a moving sum on a field in InfluxDB?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to calculate a 1 month sum of revenue data in one of my measurements. For each day, I would like the sum of the previous 30 days.

Is this possible in InfluxDB or through Grafana's query interface?

Comment: You need to try Flux. InfluxQL doesn't support moving sum (only moving average).

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks, I wasn't aware of Flux. I did some googling, but it seems all over the place. Is there somewhere I can read on Flux, how it related to Influxdb, and whether it is supported in Grafana etc?

Comment: Flux is still not generally available, it is only technical preview. There is already Grafana Flux plugin (beta release). It is developed by InfluxDB team and it is a new concept of querying data. It can be your solution, because it is more powerful than InfluxQL. Github can be good starting point - https://github.com/influxdata/flux

Comment: FYI, this is trivial task in [PromQL](https://medium.com/@valyala/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) - `sum_over_time(metric[30d])`. I hope InfluxDB will gain PromQL support soon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A moving average *is* a moving sum, divided by the number of samples. So if you want a moving sum of the past 30 values:

```
select 30*moving_average(field_name, 30) from measurement
```

### Edited to add:

As Peter Halicky points out in the comments, this is is not the past 30 days. It's the past 30 data points.

If you will always have data for every single day, it's not an issue.

If you're missing a day's data, you'll still get a 30-sample average, but it'll stretch over 31 days instead of 30.

If you don't actually care about the calendar, but want to know the past 30 days of activity, this is not a problem.

If it is a problem, there are a few work-arounds. One that's probably trickier than it sounds: ensure that there is always an entry for each day.

A more robust way is to have the reporting app do this in two steps. Something like this (haven't worked out all the details, but you get the idea):

1. find the number of data points in the past 30 days, using a query like `select count(field_name) from measurement where time > now() - 30d`.
2. Use this number (call it `n`) to form the query: `select n*moving_average(field_name, n) from measurement where time > now - 30d`.

Comment: Thanks, in hindsight this was obvious! This is the right answer

Comment: Well, this is a moving sum over last 30 samples, not over a specific time interval. This works if you have one sample per day (which is probably OP's case), but if you have ~unpredictable number of samples over a period of time, it won't work as expected.

Comment: @PeterHalicky, true. Edited to fix. Thanks!

Comment: So these would be two queries then; probably a no-go in grafana...? (Would be so much easier if InfluxDB also had a moving_sum function)

Comment: They have moving sum in Flux, but a) Flux is currently fairly beta - things will certainly change, b) last time I checked (about 6 months ago) Flux was very cpu  hungry.

Comment: The two queries might be possible: make (1) a Continuous Query, storing `n` as an integer field in the same measurement, and (2) in Grafana using both fields to form the query. Don't have time to investigate closer, sadly.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, definitely it's possible.
Just set this part of your query like this:

> ```
> SELECT sum("value") FROM "YOUR_TAG_NAME"
> WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(30d) fill(null)
> ```

[image]

Just make sure that your dashboard time included `Last 30 days` (at least).

Comment: This is similar to what I had tried, but isn't this going to just group blocks of 30 days? What I want is - for sum(11/12/2019 to 11/12/2019-30d), sum(11/11/2019 to 11/11/2019-30d) etc

Comment: This is to say, I would like each bar in the graph to be the sum of that day and the 30 days before it (moving/window sum)

Comment: Now i got it, you want to show sum of one parametr per months. Try to make group of times (every 1 month) and replace it with time group in every Query.

Comment: I'm not so good with InfluxDB queries, could you please provide or point me with an example of what/how you mean?

Comment: group by time(30d) means that every 30 days, a sum will be calculated. So the calculation will happen on days 30, 60, 90, etc. The OP wants a calculation each day for the previous 30 days. i.e. on day 30 the sum of days 1 to 30, on day 31 the sum of days 2 to 31, etc.